# Objective C Core Data: Fetch over several Entities

Tags: objective-c, core-data, nsfetchrequest

Just starting with CoreData and just wondering, how to create "complex" `FetchRequest`. I have following data-structure (minified for question):

[image]

There are several books and several people (creators). Creators can be an author, translator, illustrator (...). Some "Creator" have several "roles", that`s why I ended up with the "CreatorBook-Entity", because sometimes the same creator has different roles for different books..

Anyway... In the app I show the `Book` and there's a CollectionView with other `Books` from the same Author (=`Creator` with the `role= Author`). I tried to create a `FetchRequest` but didn`t know how to combine the different Entities, so at the moment I iterate through CoreData like the following:

```
//Get all Creators from Book and get the first Author
Creator* author;
NSSet* creatorSet = self.book.creator;  
if( [creatorSet count] > 0 ){
    for(CreatorBook *uObjects in creatorSet){
        if([uObjects.role isEqualToString:@"Author"]){
            author = uObjects.creator;
            break;    //get first author 
        }
    }
}

//Get all the Book from the same Author
if(author != nil){

    NSSet* authorBooks = author.book;

    NSMutableArray* books = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    for(CreatorBook* object in authorBooks){
        Book* a = object.book;

        [books addObject:a];

    }
    _authorBookCollection = books;

    [self.bookPreview reloadData];
}
```

Is there a way to get the same result with one `FetchRequest`?

How can I get all `Books` if there are more than one `Author`? (my code above stops at the first)

Is it possible to fetch all `Books` ordered by an attribute from Creator (for example the authors fullname (more than one author -> show book several times))?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, your attribute name `creator` for the Book entity is misleading. Potentially, a book has more than one creator, i.e. an author, illustrator, etc. So I used `creators` (in the plural) to reflect the to-many relationship. Similarly, I renamed the to-many relationship from Creator to the join table `books`.

Second, I am assuming that the book has only one author - or one creator with the same role. Of course, it is thinkable that this could be different (there is a solution for that case as well).

```
NSSet *creatorsOfThisBook = book.creators;
Creator *authorOfThisBook = [[creatorsOfThisBook filteredSetUsingPredicate:
   [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"role = %", @"author"]] anyObject];
NSSet *booksByThisAuthor = [[authorOfThisBook.books filteredSetUsingPredicate:
   [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"role = %", @"author"]]
   valueForKeyPath:@"book"];
```

You can see that if a Creator is only an author, you could leave out the second predicate.